# I can't add data to an SQL record

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to add data to a Mysql Database with this code:

```
$sql = mysql_query("UPDATE members SET name = '$name' WHERE id = '$_SESSION['username']' ");
```

but when I runn it I get the following error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE),
>   expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number
>   (T_NUM_STRING)

What have I done wrong?

Comment: For starters **do not** use `mysql_` functions. they are not supported anymore and not safe. Use `PDO` *or* `mysqli_` instead. You are also fully open to `mysqli injection`, you could easily prevent that with using those other methods. In this case `'$_SESSION['username']'` this seems very incorrect. You should do something like this: `id = ".$_SESSION['username']);` Then again, **do NOT** use `mysql_` functions, as you *will* get hacked like this *and* your code will break over time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use like this:

```
mysqli_query($connection,"UPDATE members SET name = '.$name.' WHERE id = ".$_SESSION['username']);
```

Comment: Thank you, but now I get this error: Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given

Comment: thats because vinod's answer uses mysql**i**_query. read nytrixes answer about mysqli.

Comment: ohh sorry i forgot to put connection so you got error... mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE members SET name = '.$name.' WHERE id = ".$_SESSION['username']);

Answer (score 1):

## How to fix your current issue

In order to *fix* this, you have to fix this part: `'$_SESSION['username']'`. Because as you can see you are in a double string with `'`  (that's the best I can explain it). Therefor you need to change your query to something like this.

```
$sql = mysql_query("UPDATE members SET name = '$name' WHERE id = ".$_SESSION['username']);
```

---

**WARNING**:

You should **not** use `mysql_` functions anymore! *Why?* read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php) question on SO about it, you **really** shouldn't use it anymore.

---

## How to do mysql properly

Now, what should you use? Learn how to use `PDO` *or* `mysqli_`, you can learn `PDO` [here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and `mysqli_` [here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)

While you are at that, you should also learn what `sql injection` is, it's the next step to make your projects secure and better. Read all about that [here](http://bobby-tables.com/), there are some great examples and explanations there.

Now at last, here is an example how to use `mysqli`:

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

$stmt = $conn->prepare(UPDATE members SET name =? WHERE id =?);
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $name, $id);

$name = "Nytrix";
$id = $_SESSION['username'];
$stmt->execute();

$stmt->close();
$conn->close();
```

Preparing a statement like that, and binding the values in a later stage takes away the risk of `sql injection` aswell.

I hope this has helped you clearify a bit on the topic of mysql.